# Spring BeanCreationException when deploying in HCP

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, sap-cloud-platform

Hello 2 days trying to deploying a project in HCP (Hana Cloud Platform) but without success. When I try to deploying receive errors. This error which I think is a problem and stops the whole process is as follows:

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListenerorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [/usr/sap/ljs/webapps/SAPTasking/WEB-INF/classes/spring-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5016)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.TomcatServletContainer.startWebApplication(TomcatServletContainer.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication.start(StandardWebApplication.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.extender.WebContainerBundleCustomizer.addingBundle(WebContainerBundleCustomizer.java:49)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:467)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEventPrivileged(Framework.java:1568)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEvent(Framework.java:1504)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEvent(Framework.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.web.war.deployer.WARDeployer.start(WARDeployer.java:780)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.internal.StandardApplicationDeployer.startDeployables(StandardApplicationDeployer.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.internal.StandardApplicationDeployer.bulkDeploy(StandardApplicationDeployer.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.hot.HotDeploymentFileSystemListener.bulkDeployIfNotDeployed(HotDeployerFileSystemListener.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.hot.HotDeploymentFileSystemListener.onInitialEvent(HotDeployerFileSystemListener.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.util.io.FileSystemChecker.notifyListenersOnInitialEvent(FileSystemChecker.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.util.io.FileSystemChecker.handleInitialFiles(FileSystemChecker.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.util.io.FileSystemChecker.check(FileSystemChecker.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.hot.WatchTask.run(WatchTask.java:48)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:812)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;........
```

What can it get this problem. More interesting is that when I run the project locally do not have these problems.

Here are my spring-config.xml and pom.xml:

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>SAPTasking</groupId>
    <artifactId>SAPTasking</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- 
      The HANA JDBC driver. Needs the HANA client installed, and the ngdbc.jar added to local mvn repo:

      mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/usr/sap/hdbclient/ngdbc.jar -DgroupId=com.sap -DartifactId=ngdbc -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
       --> 
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sap</groupId>
        <artifactId>ngdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.geocoder-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>geocoder-java</artifactId>
        <version>0.16</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-core.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-core.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-core.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-core.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
          <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
          <version>1.9.6</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-core.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
         <version>${spring-core.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- hibernate -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Hibernate uses slf4j for logging, for our purposes here use the simple backend -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Dependency for fix hibernate -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>xerces</groupId>
          <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
          <version>2.11.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>xalan</groupId>
          <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
          <version>2.7.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Dependency for fix hibernate -->

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
          <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
          <version>4.4.1</version>
      </dependency>


      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
      </dependency>

<!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.Final</version>
            <classifier>tests</classifier>
        </dependency>
 -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL database driver -->
        <!--<dependency>-->
          <!--<groupId>mysql</groupId>-->
          <!--<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>-->
          <!--<version>5.1.34</version>-->
          <!--</dependency>-->

        <dependency>
          <groupId>log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.15</version>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
              <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
              <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
              <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
              <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
              <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- commons -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- joda time -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
          <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.maxmind.db</groupId>
          <artifactId>maxmind-db</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jodd</groupId>
          <artifactId>jodd-http</artifactId>
          <version>${jodd.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jodd</groupId>
          <artifactId>jodd-json</artifactId>
          <version>${jodd.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
          <artifactId>nevado-jms</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

      </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <spring-core.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring-core.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.4</commons-io.version>
        <aws-version>1.9.15</aws-version>
        <jodd.version>3.6.5</jodd.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>WebContent/Certs</directory>
                            <targetPath>Certs</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>WebContent/WEB-INF/lib</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

**spring-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.entqa"/>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.entqa.dao"/>

    <!-- SuccessFactors Endpoint -->
    <bean id="sfEndpoint" class="com.entqa.sfapi.SuccessFactorsEndpoint">
        <property name="ODataURL" value="https://performancemanager5.successfactors.eu/odata/v2/" />
        <property name="companyID" value="********"/>
        <property name="apiUser" value="*******"/>
        <property name="apiPassword" value="*****"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- json mapper -->
    <bean id="mapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper"/>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:system.properties"/>

    <bean id="sqsConnectorFactory" class="org.skyscreamer.nevado.jms.connector.amazonaws.AmazonAwsSQSConnectorFactory" />

    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.skyscreamer.nevado.jms.NevadoConnectionFactory">
      <property name="sqsConnectorFactory" ref="sqsConnectorFactory" />
      <property name="awsAccessKey" value="${accessKey}" />
      <property name="awsSecretKey" value="${secretKey}" />
    </bean>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/DefaultDB"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.entqa.entities"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="batch_size">5000</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HANAColumnStoreDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">NAME_SCHEMA</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <!-- end of database related -->

    <bean id="sfExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="1"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="1"/>
        <property name="queueCapacity" value="3000"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sfScheduler" class="com.entqa.tasks.sfsf.TransientTaskScheduler"></bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: You are using a hibernate version which supports/expects JPA 2.1 and which isn't available on the server. Either package the API with your app or downgrade hibernate.

Comment: @M.Deinum When get absolutely clean project with the same version of hibernate and jpa then no problem.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The stack trace is celery are using JPA api before 2.1 with a hibernate version that expects that version. That is simply not going to work...

Comment: @M.Deinum I mean that when do a clean design and put a version of hibernate 4.3.7.Final version of JPA API 2.1. Then the server no problem. But the project above gives me a problem and I can not understand why.I will try to downgrade versions Hiberante and hope to get. I apologize if it is a mix.

Comment: There is a mix somewhere in this project the fact that it works in clean project doesn't mean anything, it only tells you that it can work. There is a wrong mix of dependencies somewhere in your war or on the server (and you are using parent first class loading not sure how that works in that environment).